# Compiling CUDA or OpenCL to llvm IR

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, clang, gpgpu

Clang can translate CUDA(not complete) or OpenCL to llvm. How can it preserve the "shared" keyword, such that it knows the difference between shared and global memory?

Comment: Hi,
I've wasted three days trying to compile a CUDA kernel into llvm IR and I couldn't do it. I've tried to change the langoptions.cpp and added CUDA=1; there , but still the clang give me Error messages for cuda syntax (like _synchthreads() call). any help/note/advice on how you did it will help much.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not familiar with CUDA or OpenCL, but can advice you to look at resulting LLVM IR that is generated by frontend and see what code is being generated. Also you can look at corresponding LLVM backend to see how it utilizes shared/global memory.

Comment: From the generated llvm IR I can't see any difference of using __global and __local.

Comment: It seems like decision is made in backend. Maybe you can found more information at http://llvm.org/devmtg/2011-11/ . There are some presentations about LLVM OpenCL backend.

Comment: It would be weird that the programmer needs to explicitly manage the local memory, but it is actually managed by the backend. Anyway, thank you for the reference.